# Proof of first MVT for Integral without using Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

first MVT for integral states that

for function $f$ that is continuous over $[a,b]\,\,$
${\large \exists{c}\in(a,b): f(c) = {\frac{1}{b-a}}\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \,dx}$

and I don't understand the proof without using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus the Proof goes like this.

since f is continuous over $[a,b]$ $f$ will have a minimum $m$ and a maximum $M$ in $[a,b]$ giving us

$${\large \int_{a}^{b}m\,dx \leq \int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx \leq \int_{a}^{b}M\,dx}$$

$${\large (b-a)m \leq \int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx \leq (b-a)M}$$

$${\large m \leq \frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx \leq M}$$

by the intermediate value theorem, the proof says we get $\large c\in(a,b)$ but why? **I don't get why the intermediate value theorem tells us** $\large c\in(a,b)$ because iv learned that the **intermediate value theorem** is

if f is continuous over $[a,b]$ and $f(a) \neq f(b)$ then there exists c in (a,b) such that f(c) is between f(a) and f(b)

so if this is the same intermediate value theorem used in the Proof, my question is why is there no condition for $f(a) \neq f(b)$ and even if so, shouldn't it be $m, M$ as  $f(a), f(b)$
and $${\large m < \frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx < M}$$
giving us $c \in (x_m, x_M) \,\, f(x_m)=m, f(x_M)=M$

I'm confused about how this works.

and also the reason why I'm trying to find proof of MVT that doesn't use the fundamental theorem of calculus is that I just don't like how we prove the fundamental theorem of calculus using MVT then use it to prove the MVT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that minimum and maximum are attained, i.e. there exist $x_{\min}, x_{\max}\in [a,b]$ so that $f(x_{\min})=\min_{x\in [a,b]} f(x)$ and $f(x_{\max})=\max_{x\in [a,b]} f(x)$. So shrink the function to $[x_{\min},x_{\max}]$ where I w.l.o.g. assumed $x_{\min}<x_{\max}$. Now if $f(x_{\max})>f(x_{\min})$ you can apply the intermediate value theorem on the interval $[x_{\min},x_{\max}]$ and then $c\in [x_{\min},x_{\max}]\subset [a,b]$. But if $f(x_{\min})=f(x_{max})$ the function is constant and it is obvious that such $c$ exists.
Note that the intermediate value theorem tells you (for your setting) for any $y\in [f(x_{\min}),f(x_{\max})]$ there exists $c\in [x_{\min},x_{\max}]$ so that $f(c)=y$. Since $f(x_{\min})\leq\frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b f(x) dx \leq f(x_{\max})$ the term $\frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b f(x) dx$ is a potential $y$.

Comment: i understand, when $f(x_{m}) = f(x_M)$ but i still don't get $c \in (a,b)$ if my understanding is correct you're awnser says $c \in (x_m, x_M)$ so if $c \in (a,b)$ but $c \notin (x_m, x_M)$ then it still dose'nt prove it.


edit: the part "shrink the function to $[x_{min}, x_{max}]$" is that approvable?

Comment: The proof is using that $c\in [x_{\min},x_{\max}]$ and hence $x\in [a,b]$ since $[x_{\min},x_{\max}]\subset [a,b]$.